# how to pass json array from jsp to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jsp

My jsp code is

```
 <% List selected = (List) session.getAttribute("clist");

   JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
        tmp = new JSONObject();
        tmp.put("Id", selected.get(i));

        arr.put(tmp);
    }%>
```

and i am using hidden field to pass this array to javascript

```
  <input type='hidden' id="agencycontactid" name="agencycontactid" value="<%=(null != arr) ? arr : ""%>" />
```

here **arr** gives value **arr=[{"Id":"9"},{"Id":"11"}]**

My javascript code is

```
  var s=$('#agencycontactid').val(); alert(s);
```

But alert gives only **[{**

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Change type hidden to text to see if it shows correct json value. I am sure the issue is there.

Comment: @gaurav You are absolutely right.Please tell me how to set that arr value to hidden field

Comment: Your input tag looks like this: `<input ... value="[{"Id":...>` so the value attribute is only `[{` due to the `"` in the string you're trying to pass

Comment: @icke how to overcome this problem

Comment: See my answer below, I hope it helps.

Comment: Try using   <input type='hidden' id="agencycontactid" name="agencycontactid" value='<%=(null != arr) ? arr : ""%>' /> (Notice the value=' instead of value=")

Comment: Thanks all for giving response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change value attr from

```
value="<%=(null != arr) ? arr : ""%>"
```

to

```
value='<%=(null != arr) ? arr : ""%>'
```

Comment: it not working it gives error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0):

The variable `arr` from your scriptlet is passed to the HTML as a string with the content `[{"Id":"9"},{"Id":"11"}]`, so your input tag will look like this: `<input type='hidden' id="agencycontactid" name="agencycontactid" value="[{"Id":"9"},{"Id":"11"}]" />`. So the value attribute will only contain the part of the string up to the first `"`, i.e. `[{`.

You could try to put the json data in a place where `"` doesn't interfere with the HTML, like inside a hidden tag like so

```
<div id="jsondata">
    <%=arr%>
</div>
```

or put the scriptlet inside a `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = <%=arr%>;
</script>
```

Changing the delimiters of the value attribute to `'` instead of `"` would also work but would break as soon as your json data contains strings with `'` in them. However if you are sure that will never be the case, that is by far the easiest fix.